# Apache .htaccess is not listening to whitelisting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I've setup an .htaccess file to implement a password protected environment.
The idea is that every user that lands on this domain will be asked to login with credentials (using .htpasswd). The only exception is that when I go to that domain, I'm granted access immediately. At this moment, everyone has to give credentials, so my whitelisting is not working properly..

Can anybody spot the mistake I've made?

```
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Name"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/user/magento2/pub/.htpasswd

        ## IP Whitelist
        # Allow access for this ip
        <RequireAny>
          Require valid-user
          Require ip <my ip>
        </RequireAny>
```

Comment: what IP did you enter? I mean the 127.0.0.1 or the NIC-assigned one?

Comment: My current ip that is returned by https://whatismyipaddress.com/

Comment: ok, but did you run the apache locally? My idea is that the apache did not take your IP as you expected

Comment: This is on a live server

Comment: is the server behind some load balancer?

Comment: No..But can you something wrong with the provided setup?

Comment: I think that just apache does not recognize the IP address as you expected. I can't help here anymore

Comment: If you got any server-side scripting language available, create a test page that outputs the requesting IP address - and check if that is actually the one you were expecting.

Comment: ...Or check your server's access log for the IP. Otherwise, the directives you've posted look OK. Do you have any other directives that might be conflicting? What version of Apache are you using?

Comment: My boss pointed out that there is varnish enabled, which makes the .htaccess unstable.

Comment: @MrWhite, the IP is correct so it's varnish that's making things difficult